# WebDAV get folder/file tags in json response?

Tags: json, webdav

I know by default the response from a webdav server looks something like:

```
{
  href: href,
  propstat: propstat,
  prop: prop,
  resourceType: resourceType,
  collection: collection
}
```

Has anyone had any experience adding the file/folder tags to the response? or any other field for that matter?

This is a Beehive server, which provides an xml response initially

Comment: WebDAV does not have JSON responses. If you are getting that response, it means that you're using a server that has a custom/non-standard json response. You should include the server you're using in your question, because the answer will be specific to that server.